# mysql Query Return Code

Tags: mysql, sql

I am Writing a MYSQL Stored Procedure.  In that i know using HANDLER we can check the condition for SELECT STATEMENT.

```
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND
SET  NO_MORE_ROWS = TRUE;
```

In DB2 we can check the return code using SQLCODE immediatly after the statement.

Please let me know how i need to handle the Duplicate Index, More than one Row, Cursor Problem, Data mismatch in Source variable against table fields.  Is there a way in MYSQL.

Basically  i want to know in MYSQL How to handle the below condition.

```
  SELECT  -  NOT FOUND, MORE THAN ONE ROW, EXCEPTION, DATATYPE MISMATCH IN TO CONDITION
  INSERT  -  DUPLICATE INDEX, DATATYPE MISMATCH, OTHER INERT FAILURE
  UPDATE  -  NO DATA FOR UPDATE, UPDATE WHERE CONDITION NOT MET
  DELETE  -  NOT DELETED BECAUSE OF FOREIGN KEY ISSUE.
  CURSOR  -  CURSOR FAILURE
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As documented under [`DECLARE ... HANDLER` Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/declare-handler.html):

> The ***`condition_value`*** for [`DECLARE ... HANDLER`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/declare-handler.html) indicates the specific condition or class of conditions that activates the handler:
>
> - A MySQL error code (a number) or an SQLSTATE value (a 5-character string literal). You should not use MySQL error code 0 or SQLSTATE values that begin with `'00'`, because those indicate success rather than an error condition. For a list of MySQL error codes and SQLSTATE values, see [Section C.3, “Server Error Codes and Messages”](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/error-messages-server.html).